# I added a link why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, editing-help

I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13529584) edit suggestion and it was rejected for the following reason: **This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.**

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) meta question and its answer I found:

*To add related resources or links that will help someone answer the post, or provide context*

*Linking to other resources related to the post.*

The answer to original question is a clear no, but still the answerer wants to provide multiple alternatives. One more link would have not been a bad idea :)

So is my edit suggestion still a bad edit? or are the guidelines on meta not good or something else?

Comment: IMHO, that should have been a comment on the question or the asnwer.

Comment: You mean it doesn't fit the category of linking or adding related resources?

Comment: I usually just post such as a comment, addressing the author to include the link there. I always feel that there might be a reason the author didn't include that - and as this would add something to the post, and is not something already there, it would probably be against the original intentions. I would consider it valid, if e.g. you add a link to an official documentation of something *that is already in the post*. Like changing java.util.Date to a link [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ppeterka already pointed it out in the comments - adding links to resources makes sense if it's an official or canonical resource. If it is not official or canonical, then you're just putting words into an OP's mouth. This is frowned upon, especially if the answer is upvoted and/or accepted.

More links is not necessarily better - in fact, it can be worse. A user can only read one page at a time. The more links there are to choose from, the more they have to prioritize which one they want to read. So consider carefully before adding links.

If you do feel the link is relevant, you can add it as a comment.

That said, I don't think that is a very good answer in the first place. It basically says "No, but you can do something else, look here [links]".
A better edit would be to extract the relevant information from one of the linked posts, and edit that into the answer. Then future visitors would not have to visit another link, but would have a possible solution right in front of them.
(If you make this kind of edit, be sure to explain that you did so in the Edit Summary - reviewers tend to reject edits that add large amounts of extra info. When it's not clear where all that extra info came from, then it looks like an attempt to hijack a post).

Of course, editing in info from other SO posts should only be done if the question isn't a duplicate.  If it's a duplicate, then just flag/vote to close it.

Comment: I see, so you're saying I edit with actual code and name the edit's title as : "added actual code from the links"?

Comment: @Honey That would be a good edit summary. It's best to copy code _and_ a little explanation.